# Google Appengine daily budget not reflected in quota

Tags: google-app-engine, email, billing, quota

Dear AppEngine people (I understand that all AppEngine support has moved to StackOverflow - if I am mistaken then sorry for posting this here), I have a very serious problem that I hope you can help me to resolve.

Yesterday I enabled billing with a daily budget of $500 on my application (friendbazaar.appspot.com), and my billing status is "Enabled". However, I am still showing that I have maxed out my usage of recipients emailed at 100 of 100.

The quota was just reset 2 hours ago, and so I don't understand why this has not reflected the updated quotas based on the billing settings.

This is a big problem, since I recently sent out invitations to members of my other sites (over 100K people) to sign up for this new site - and since email authorization is required to complete the registration process, I am totally hosed and have basically pissed off a lot of customers by making them register and then never sending them the email to complete the process.

Please let me know if this can be fixed, and what the normal delay is for appengine quotas to reflect billing settings.

Comment: _Technical_ questions should be posted on Stack Overflow. Billing and other questions that don't fit the SO remit should still go to the list or via other support channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the billing FAQ's

**Why did my mail quota not increase after I enabled billing?**

*Google will wait until the first payment is cleared before increasing your mail quota. This means it will take at least seven days to get the higher quota.*

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#quota_increase

DISCLAIMER - I am not affiliated with Google in any way, nor do I believe you can get an official response from them via stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, for the info. That is exactly what I needed to know (but didn't want to hear that).

Comment: Now that appengine support has moved to StackOverflow (https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/0414d42be2f4bde0) - where are we supposed to ask administrative related questions - ie. if I really had needed someone from google to address a problem?

Comment: There are definitely Googlers active on Stack Overflow (I'm one of them). Regarding billing questions, you can use the form linked at the bottom of the FAQ if you have a billing problem (https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#morehelp)

Answer (score 0):

GAE no longer supports sending more than 100 emails per day as per their tech support (May 2016). Instead they are nudging people over to SendGrid. Its unfortunate that they are reducing the capabilities of GAE for something as basic as transactional email. I can see why marketing or bulk emails would be frowned upon but for the core transactional emails most apps/sites require it would be nice to have a native, low cost, option. Off to check out Amazon's email service!