# How do I set a cost limit in Google Developers Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, traffic, cost-management, google-cloud-billing

Some functions in the Google Developers Console, like the Analytics API, are free until you reach a quota. Other functions, like Google Cloud Storage, create costs from the first click.

When I upload a file under `https://console.developers.google.com/ > Storage > Cloud Storage > Storage Browser` and I make this file publicly available, I pay about $0.12 per GB traffic.

But theoretically the traffic to this link could explode, e.g. because of sudden popularity. Therefore I would like to set something like a daily or monthly cost limit.

Q: How do I protect myself from overly high costs in the Google Developers Console?

Comment: As of July/2017, it still is not possible to limit GCE usage by budget. If some evil ones DDOS your application/database (e.g. download 1MB file again and again from hundreds of hosts/threads), it is possible that you will see hundreds to thousands of dollars of a bill after you wake up in the morning. Not only that, you won't simply be able to turn your app back on again, until you find a way to resolve that problem because DDOS can come back anytime later as your app gets bigger.

Comment: I'm reluctant to use gcp if I can't even cap my spending in currency units.

Comment: @user482594 I got a $20,000 surprise for a website that I didn't even finish. I will never use Google Cloud for dev or testing again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of July 2017 you can set budgets that send notifications via email **but do not cap spending**:

[image: screenshot of GCS documentation warning that budget does not cap API usage]

To set an alert-only budget, which **will not cap spending**:

1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console.
2. Open the console left side menu and click Billing
3. If you have more than one billing account, click the billing account name.
4. On the left, click Budgets & alerts.

Official help page: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293540?hl=en

Comment: I don't see anything there that suggests that it (settings budgets and alerts) will "restrict the overall spending".   My read is that it just sends an e-mail alert!

Comment: Yeah it's still really unclear, shame on them for this.

Comment: When setting a budget, it actually explicitly says 'Setting a budget does not cap resource or API consumption.' So it is just alerts - not hard limits. You _can_ however set API usage limits elsewhere.

Comment: Still valid in 2021

Comment: Is still valid in 2022 ?

Comment: Yeah it seems like it @RajendraAVerma

Comment: and in 2023 ... shame on you google

Comment: For those stumbling upon this, you can use cloud functions to implement a kill-switch. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify. This is what I plan on doing myself.

Comment: still vaild in 2024 ?

Answer (score 35):

You cannot. I asked Google about this, here's their response, from May 7 2016:

(GCE = Google cloud engine. No spending limits.
GAE = Google app engine — yes it has spending limits.)

> ... you are eligible for support on ... only ...
> ... [*various helpful links*] ...
>
> That been said, at the moment there is no a feature that allows you to
> configure a limited budget on GCE. This feature is certainly available
> for GAE [1]. As you mentioned in your comments, you either can totally
> shut down your VMs (will depend on your use case) or set the VMs to
> send you alerts if they reach a certain traffic limit [2].
>
> Sincerely,
>
> *Someone's first name*
> Technical Solutions Representative
> Google Cloud Platform
>
> [1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas
> [2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options

@wmdry, you wrote: *"traffic to this link could explode*" — I'm afraid of this too. That's why I asked Google about this. And I'm planning to avoid Google's CDN because of this, and use another CDN provider instead, which has spending limits. Because, unlike Nginx, I don't see any way for me to rate limit / throttle Google's CDN.

I do plan to use GCE (Google Cloud Engine) though. Therefore, right now I'm reading about how to rate limit my Nginx server. Because if I just configure Nginx correctly, then those $0.12 / GB you mentioned, cannot possible explode to ... like $10k in a month? What if Google sends a $10k bill when I'm back from an a few week's vacation, just because of my hobby project and a few people downloading a 1 MB movie over and over again forever (because: evil). Hmm, & the bigger & faster my servers, the higher the risk.

I hope Google will add spending limits, because I did want to use Google's CDN.

**Update 2020:** Apparently this does bite people from time to time — look here:
*"Burnt $72k testing Firebase and Cloud Run and almost went bankrupt"*, Dec 08, 2020, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25372336,
In that case, they could contact Google and in the end didn't need to pay.

Answer (score 21):

I found that Google's documentation now provides two methods to actually limit the cost of a GCP project. It involves the following setup:

1. Create a Cloud Function that [checks the cost against the budget](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify), and carries out a certain action if the cost exceeds the budget. Google's Documentation provides a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/billing/main.py) code snip that can either shutdown all VM instances in a Project or disable the billing for a project. Shutting down all VMs would stop all VM-related cost but you get to keep your data (and still have to pay for the storage). Disabling the billing for a project would effectively zap all cost-related activities and you could lose data. You can name the Cloud Function "budget-enforcer".
2. The Google code snip as provided above has a hard coded ZONE variable. Remember to change it to match your zone!
3. Create a Service Account to run the Cloud Function "budget-enforcer". For shutting down VMs, the Service Account would need role "Compute Instance Admin (v1)". For disabling billing on a project, the Service Account would need role "Project Billing Manager".
4. Set a Topic for the Cloud Function (I call mine "proj-name-stop-vm" and "proj-name-disable-bill").
5. Set up a budget alert as usual, and connect it to one of the Pub/Sub topic above.

Please be noted that Google's documentation did mention that there could be a delay between the cost exceeds a budget and the function is triggered, so you should build in a buffer if you have an absolute hard cost limit. I use 90% of the budget as the trigger line for shutting down my instances.

Comment: Yan -- I tried this, but am getting a "KeyError": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099501/disabling-billing-on-google-cloud-using-google-cloud-function-keyerror-data any chance you know what's going on?

Comment: I've commented on your question.

Answer (score 13):

The **API usage** can be limited with a hard limit:

> Depending on the API, you can explicitly cap requests in a variety of
>   ways, including: requests per day, requests per 100 seconds, and
>   requests per 100 seconds per user. You might want to limit the
>   billable usage by setting caps. For example, to prevent getting billed
>   for usage beyond the free courtesy usage limits, you can set requests
>   per day caps

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)

Comment: Documentation says: "**Quota limits are not always entirely precise**, because there is some latency between when a quota is surpassed 
and when the enforcement begins. When using quota as a tool to limit billing, allow some buffer."
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage
There are no details in the doc what "some buffer" exactly means. => Actually, there is no hard limit !?

Comment: I just chatted with support they said a buffer of 20 % is fine. If I use the following three APIs and corresponding limits per day, I won't reach the free total limit of $200 per month.
* Distance Matrix API: 170 Elements per day  
* Directions API: 170 Elements per day
* Geocoding API: 340 requests per day

Answer (score 7):

You can combine budget pub/sub alerts with a cloud function that can disable billing on your entire account if a threshold is met.

**Full Tutorial Here:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiTg8RPpGG4

**GitHub Repo Here:** https://github.com/aioverlords/Google-Cloud-Platform-Killswitch

To Disable Billing

```
const _disableBillingForProject = async projectName => {
const res = await billing.updateBillingInfo({
    name: projectName,
    resource: {
        billingAccountName: ''
    }, // Disable billing
});
console.log(res);
console.log("Billing Disabled");
return `Billing disabled: ${JSON.stringify(res.data)}`;
};
```

Comment: Great idea actually, although I have one suggestion, since we should follow the principle of least privilege, we should ideally have a service account attached to that Cloud Function which will only have the required permissions. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access Though as you mentioned, there's still a huge issue as the budget alerts isn't real time, but it is the next best thing. Maybe we can have a higher threshold at which our budget alert is triggered, so the notification gets triggered earlier and as a consequence, this CF is executed earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Simply go to the developer console:

https://console.developers.google.com/project

- Select your project.
- Select "billings & settings"
- Enable billing.

Then go to Compute/AppEngine/Settings and set a daily budget.

[image]

Comment: I do not have this option. I have never created an app engine application. I use the cloud storage function. This is my sidebar: [link](http://i.imgur.com/DvuSvvV.png)

Comment: You have an app-engine tag however.

Comment: Try to create a new project from the google dev console. This is not the same as a new app engine project and therefore the option you described will not appear (afaik, see my link/screenshot above)

Comment: it asks me for a billing account now on doing that, so things seem to have changed a little lately.

Comment: Does this setting really affect cloud storage though? Isn't this just for app engine?

Comment: Excellent question. you "enable billing" but yes, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @quano as I understand it, Google calls the whole project (for which you activate billing for) a "App". So this billing limit should effect every used service (no matter if Storage, Compute, Big Data, etc.) within the "App" (project). But if you want to be 100% sure I would suggest you to contact Google support directly (they should know this for sure :D ).

Comment: I'm fairly sure this answer is incorrect. The spending limits are just for AppEngine, not for GCE in general. See my answer below — I actually contacted Google, and asked.

Comment: @quano Yes only for app engine. GCE = no spending limits. See my answer below.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Google Cloud console, and then to **Billing / Budgets and Alerts** and create a new budget for one or all your projects. You can select which services should be included in the limit and set a monthly amount that should not be exceeded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! just to be clear, this means that no matter what (assuming i selected all projects and services). I will not pay above the cost I've specified, right?

Comment: @MTZ4 I think so, but you might want to check with someone from Google.

Comment: This option just sends you notifications, it doesn't limit your spending.