# Appengine increase email message quota - how long to wait before approval?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, quota

I recently created a new application on the AppEngine that verifies user email addresses as part of the user registration process. This requires sending an email confirmation to each user that registeres on my site, so being able to send out more than 100 emails is very important to have this application function properly.

My application is running on the "monthly" billing cycle, which means that to increase email quota, an increase must manually be requested by clicking on a link on the "Quota Details" page (versus the old system in which email quota would automatically be increased after the first billing went through).

I requested an increase to my AppEngine email quota 5 days ago, and am still waiting for approval. Is it normal that processing takes so long for a request to increase quota? Currently my request status is reported as "Your request for increased email quota has been received and is currently under review.".

I am posting this question to check if other people have experienced a similar processing time for increasing mail quota, or if this seems unusual.  Is there anything that I can do to speed up this process?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my initial contact by email after about 1 week.

They will ask you to either make a bill of $10 to get approved, or send them another application's ID you own which had a bill cleared.

So in any case, its something money can solve.

Comment: I just got my approval. It took 1 week, just as you had experienced.

Comment: congratulations Alexander :) Just for curious what is the App you're building?

Comment: Thanks Lawrence! The most recent app that I am building is "MellowDating.com" - I have built an open-source AppEngine platform for launching dating websites, and this is the 8th site that I have launched, but the first one that I have launched with the new "monthly billing cycle"

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt Did you make the $10 contribution? I've waited 3 weeks and it still says under review.

Comment: @jack i've been waiting two weeks now.

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894174/google-appengine-daily-budget-not-reflected-in-quota

Answer (score 3):

The approved answer is no longer valid as on May '2016. GAE no longer supports more than 100 email recipients per day. This policy shift was confirmed by their tech support. Instead they are nudging people to use SendGrid (why SendGrid specifically versus other options is unknown - there is no special deal for using SendGrid from GAE). Sadly, GAE no longer has an internal solution for all those transactional emails that most apps/sites require. Its suprising that they are removing this capability and recommending 3rd parties rather than making their service more robust.